# MDict can‘t load more than 122 files as group

Tags: macos, catalina

I had issue with [MDict](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mdict/id389083586) which others or the developer of app can‘t reproduce.

I can't load more than 122 files as groups.

If i using more than 122 dict files, app can't show, it shows fail to open file. The files not corrupt, all of them works for others and developer.

**The issue only when loading all files together as group.**

*I reinstalled new macos, issue doesn't solve it.*

Here is log file of app:
Should be normal way;

Found dictionary:/Users/**/Downloads/pro/****, added to list

```
Open file failed, reason:No such file or directory
Open file failed, reason:No such file or directory
Open file failed, reason:Too many open files
Open file failed, reason:Too many open files
Fail to load dict:/Users/**/Downloads/pro/*****, Error:Fail to open file
```

Files is ok, if i opened only one file is ok.
I appreciate for helping.

Comment: Hi Shawky, welcome to Ask Different. Have you contacted the developer of the app for help? Which app is it? What does it do? The error messages "No such file or directory" point to missing files, could that be the problem?

Comment: My college tested app, with same file and more 370 files, it is works like charm with him.

Comment: What is the result of `sysctl kern.maxfiles kern.maxfilesperproc`? Are there other applications running which open a lot of files? Is the problem the same if you run the application immediately after a reboot? If you create a new user account on your Mac and try there, does it happen as well?

Comment: Hi Nohillside, No other apps running, i created new user account, even i tried re-install new MacOS. My system now is new, doesn’t install any thing except this app.

Comment: kern.maxfiles: 98304
kern.maxfilesperproc: 49152

Comment: The developer found the reason of problem, it is “limit the number of files and processes that are allowed to be open“, https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

Comment: When i tried, sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000 , and then open app, it is work like charm, how can i setup it? Can this setting effect on system?

Comment: Are there other solution? Many thanks

Comment: Mine solution limit maxfiles, after restart doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First solution to test:

The developer of App found the solution.

This is temporary Solution. Problem cause of apply system limit open file.

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000
```

More detail here: [Maximum limits (macOS etc.)](https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits//)

> Newer versions of macOS do not reference the file due to security
> considerations.

---

The best solution:

ref: https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

1. Download this two file: https://github.com/wilsonmar/mac-setup/blob/master/configs/limit.maxfiles.plist

https://github.com/wilsonmar/mac-setup/blob/master/configs/limit.maxproc.plist

new link：https://gist.github.com/skylock/0117ec637d468f91260927b43b816eda

1. Copy and Paste this two file in folder /Library/LaunchDaemons/
2. In terminal write this code:

> ```
> sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
> sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist
> ```

Enter, will ask for user password.

3. In terminal, write:

```
sudo ulimit -n 65536 200000
```

4. Restart, it will work like a charm!

Comment: You've posted this as a second answer. Which is fine in general, but as both answers cover the same solution, combining them into one might be better.